# Running dropwizard with same configuration as my localhost, gives error on vps

Tags: java, yaml, dropwizard, ubuntu-server

When I try to run my dropwizard application on my ubuntu server, I get an error with the conf.yml file that does not appear on my local development. This is the conf.yml

```
  server:
  type: simple
  applicationContextPath: /api
  adminContextPath: /admin
  connector:
    type: https
    port: 8433
    keyStorePath: ./keystore.jks
    keyStorePassword: mypassword
    validateCerts: true
```

This configuration on my pc gives no errors, but on the vps it says:

```
 conf.yml has an error:
  * Failed to parse configuration at: server.connector; Could not resolve type id 'https' as a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.jetty.ConnectorFactory]: known type ids = [] (for POJO property 'connector')
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: se.planetdev.ServerConfiguration["server"]->io.dropwizard.server.SimpleServerFactory["connector"])
```

is this somehow caused by ubuntu messing with the conf.yml while running? Like make the lines all on the same row or anything as .yml files should be written in a certain way.

Thanks for help!

Comment: my yml has "minus" just before the "type" field, 

server:
  applicationConnectors:
  - type: http 
    port: 11111

Comment: Hmm mine did not need that, maybe I use an earlier version of dropwizard as I don't have applicationConnectors the way you write it? However, this was solved when building with Maven Shade. :) Thanks for reply!